# How to fix MPU9250 configuration issue in device tree?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded, device-tree, iio

I have set up an i2c protocol which detects the mpu9250 at address 0x68. Now I want to configure the mpu and I have updated my dts file with the following lines of code:

```
mpu9250@68 {
    compatible = "invensense,mpu9250";
    reg = <0x68>;
    i2c-gate {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;
        ax8975@c {
            compatible = "ak,ak8975";
            reg = <0x0c>;
        };
    };
};
```

However, I get the following error on running >> dmesg | grep mpu

> > inv-mpu6050-i2c 1-0068: invalid whoami 0x40 expected 0x71 (MPU9250)

For this I have also configured the i2cmux and Industrial I/O (IIO) through the developer shell with the "make menuconfig" command. But I see no expected results. Where could I have possibly gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For an mpu9250 defined in a Linux device tree it requires compatible, reg and interrupts to be defined. More fields are required when defining for Android.

The device tree definition you've given is missing the required field interrupts

Linux kernel documentation on this :-
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/iio/imu/invensense%2Cmpu6050.yaml